# How to discover the underlying primary (or unique) key columns from an Oracle view

Tags: database, oracle, view, schema, primary-key

I was wondering whether there is a possibility for me to discover the underlying primary (or unique) key columns for all tables involved in an Oracle view. Here's an example to show what I mean:

```
CREATE TABLE t_a (
  id number(7),
  primary key(id)
);

CREATE VIEW v_a AS
SELECT * FROM t_a;
```

So by naming convention, I know that `v_a.id` is actually the primary key column of the underlying `t_a` table. Is there any way of formally discovering this information by using system views, such as `SYS.ALL_CONSTRAINTS`, `SYS.USER_CONSTRAINTS`, etc?

N.B:

- The constraints are **NOT** on the view, but on the underlying table.
- I'm not interested in the keys themselves, but in the columns of the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find that information via the user_dependencies view:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t_a
  2  (   id number(7)
  3  ,   primary key(id)
  4  )
  5  /

Table created.

SQL> CREATE VIEW v_a AS SELECT * FROM t_a
  2  /

View created.

SQL> select c.constraint_name
  2    from user_dependencies d
  3       , all_constraints c
  4   where d.name = 'V_A'
  5     and d.referenced_type = 'TABLE'
  6     and d.referenced_link_name is null
  7     and d.referenced_owner = c.owner
  8     and d.referenced_name = c.table_name
  9     and c.constraint_type = 'P'
 10  /

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_C0051559

1 row selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

**EDIT**: For possible view column names, you can use this query. Note there is no guarantee that such a column exists in your view.

```
SQL> select c.constraint_name
  2       , 'V_' || substr(c.table_name,3) || '.' || cc.column_name possible_view_column
  3    from user_dependencies d
  4       , all_constraints c
  5       , all_cons_columns cc
  6   where d.name = 'V_A'
  7     and d.referenced_type = 'TABLE'
  8     and d.referenced_link_name is null
  9     and d.referenced_owner = c.owner
 10     and d.referenced_name = c.table_name
 11     and c.constraint_type = 'P'
 12     and c.owner = cc.owner
 13     and c.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
 14  /

CONSTRAINT_NAME                POSSIBLE_VIEW_COLUMN
------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------------------
SYS_C0051561                   V_A.ID

1 row selected.
```

Comment: @Rob, thanks for the input. That's a good start. Now I need to find out that `v_a.id` is in fact the column backed by `t_a.id`, which is part of the primary key...

Comment: That's not easy, because a view is just a stored query, in other words: just text. You'd have to parse the view text.

Comment: @Rob: your query will return the unique constraints of all underlying tables. It will not return which columns (if any?) in the view are backed by a unique constraint.

Comment: @Vincent: he asked for the "keys" and not for the "key columns". I have an extra section now for the columns though.

Comment: That's what I thought. But I figured, that maybe the Oracle compiler persists this information somewhere accessible from the `SYS` schema...

Comment: @Vincent, @Rob, sorry, I chose the wrong wording for my question. I'm really curious about the key columns, not the keys.

Comment: @Rob, your EDIT would work well with my example. But unfortunately, the naming convention has too many exceptions for this to be formally acceptable. I thought of that too. Maybe there really isn't a solution...

Comment: @Rob: I took the question in the broader sense: is it possible to determine if a column in a view is unique (backed by pk)? I think that at some point Oracle may compute this information (which would have effects on ALL_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS for instance), but I don't know if this information is accessible in the dictionary views. Also it would be interesting to determine which table/column a specific view column points to (if any).

Comment: @Vincent: That's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT column_name FROM user_ind_columns
  WHERE index_name =
   (SELECT index_name FROM user_constraints
      WHERE constraint_type='P' AND table_name='T_A')
ORDER BY column_position;
```

If you want to do it for all tables that a view depends on, then change the condition on table_name to something like:

```
table_name IN (SELECT referenced_name FROM user_dependencies
                 WHERE name='view_name' AND referenced_type='TABLE')
```

Comment: thanks for the input. That's a good start. Now I need to find out that `v_a.id` is in fact the column backed by `t_a.id`, which is part of the primary key...